# Debug.Print all data in a table

Tags: vba, loops, data-extraction

I am trying to use recordset code to loop through all the fields in a table and debug.print their values and field names in an order you would naturally read the table ie from left to right across columns then onto the row below

[image: This is a sample table]

I have accomplished what I'm trying to do but only for the first row.  This is the code:

```
Sub RecordSets()
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim i As Long
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbl1")

        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
                Debug.Print rs.Fields(i).Name
                Debug.Print rs.Fields(i).Value
        Next

rs.Close
db.Close
End Sub
```

Immediate window produces following result:

```
    Category
    Clothing
    Item
    Shirt
    Price
    5
```

This is the top row and is exactly as I want.  But I cannot get any code to work accomplish this exact same thing for the other rows.  I am 99% sure I need to use a Do Until .EOF loop in conjunction with the For...Next loop but I can't get the results whatever I try or I lock access up in an infinite query.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Add a `Do while not rs.EOF` loop.  Don't forget to `rs.MoveNext` within the loop...  FYI Debug.Print only handles about 200 lines before new lines replace older ones...

Comment: Thanks.  Does ```Do Until rs.EOF``` accomplish the same thing as ```Do While not rs.EOF``` in this situation and in general?  Edit* and thanks I kind of thought debug.print wasn't returning what I wanted regardless of what I tried.  Need to write it to a string, I know.

Comment: Do while/do until are just different ways of doing pretty much the same thing: one or other might be preferable depending on the exact use case.

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
Sub RecordSets()
    Const SEP as String = vbTab
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset, numFlds As Long
    Dim i As Long, s As String, sp as string
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbl1")

    numFlds = rs.Fields.Count

    'print the headers (field names)
    For i = 0 To numFlds  - 1
        s = s & sp & rs.Fields(i).Name
        sp = SEP '<< add separator for subsequent items
    Next
    Debug.Print s

    'print the data
    sp = ""  '<< clear the separator
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        For i = 0 To numFlds - 1
            s = s & sp & rs.Fields(i).Name
            sp = SEP
        Next
        Debug.Print s
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    db.Close
End Sub
```